Treated wood with mold - does it still show yellow/green under UV light?
I had mold on the floor joists in the basement from a previous water leak.  I treated it with an excellent mold treatment solution.  Now that it is treated, it still shows some yellow, yellow-green under UV light.  Does that mean the mold is still alive and needs another treatment?

Have you tried your UV lamp on known-good wood? You may be able to see some fluorescence there too.
